# What is the tense in this sentence? Is the verb in conditional?

Tags: conditionals

In what verbal tense is "*were*"? Could it be considered conditional? Or a preterite in subjunctive mood?

- *The best way I can explain it to you is by saying that, for a second or two, I felt as though, instead of going to the centre of a continent, I **were** about to set off for the center of the earth.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behave as if it was or it were](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146361/behave-as-if-it-was-or-it-were). There are other relevant threads; [she laughed as though there was/were a chance he might have ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178432/she-laughed-as-though-there-was-were-a-chance-he-might-have-said-anything-els) looks more like an exact duplicate, but was closed _as_ a duplicate of the former.

Comment: It has no tense -- it's a mood form, often called 'irrealis'. The expression "as though" marks this as a comparative construction. The "as though" phrase introduces the manner complement: ... _as though I were about to set off for the center of the earth_."